# Image/Media Server That Works With Postgres

Tags: php, postgresql, image-processing, nginx, media

I was recently had an nginx + php-fpm server that was serving images like so:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo file_get_contents('example_image.png');
exit();
```

What I am came to realize, whether the image was cached or not, there was a huge peformance hit on the server. CPU utilization was extremely high, 100% with a minimal amount of connections. So I started to offload the images to a CDN and there was an immediate performance improvement but in some cases I still do require the image to be served through a server, which has brought me to the idea of image/media server.

My question is, is there a specific type of server that I should be using? One that can communicate with a database to find the images location and serve it? File system type? Or am I better off keeping just firing up another nginx + php-fpm instance and create a cdn like structure implementation where:

```
media.example.com
```

points only to that server, thus there is no performance impact on the web server?

Comment: Why not serve images directly by nginx? Do you really need PHP for that?

Comment: The example isn't totally accurate because the images are related to ids, thus it looks up where the image location stored in the db, and then serves it.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you're treating your image like a string instead of a stream. There's absolutely no need to load it all up in php using `file_get_contents()` and proceeding to `echo` the mess. Look up things such as `readfile()` and PG-related LOB functionality:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
exit;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

```
$db = new PDO('pgsql:dbname=test host=localhost', $user, $pass);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->beginTransaction();
$stmt = $db->prepare("select oid from BLOBS where ident = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($some_id));
$stmt->bindColumn('oid', $oid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);
$stream = $db->pgsqlLOBOpen($oid, 'r');
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
fpassthru($stream);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.pgsqllobopen.php

Along similar lines, look into cache-control related headers. There's no need to resend an image that is already in the browser's cache. Try to send 304 Not Modified when possible:

[Make PHP page return "304 Not Modified" if it hasn't been modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978496/make-php-page-return-304-not-modified-if-it-hasnt-been-modified)

Comment: I never thought an image as a stream. I will definitely give this a try and benchmark it against other implementations.

Comment: What you might want to add to your answer is information about the X-SendFile

Comment: I've never used it myself, so that wouldn't seem right. Looks neat though. Thanks for pointing it out. :-) (Feel very free to add your own answer, or to edit my own for completeness.)

Answer (score -1):

What are you serving the images for? Because I'd say if you're just serving images in PHP use a simple echo with HTML in it?

```
echo "<img src='image.png'>";
```

or if you want it to display from a variable, or whatever, just add "" inside of the '' after the IMG SRC= (like so)

```
echo "<img src='" . $this . "." . $extention . "'>";
```

It shouldn't really be impacting your server that much by displaying a image? But hey, I'm no expert.

Comment: He only needs to serve plain images, no HTML.