# Cache PHP page that echoes CSS code

Tags: php, html, css, apache, http

Following the accepted answer [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950734/change-css-value-with-php), I am trying to create a stylesheet that is editable with PHP.

### What's happening...

I am trying to make the stylesheet (named `css.php`) cache in the user's browser so that he/she does not have to load it on every pageload, and have set the following headers to do so:

```
header('Content-Type: text/css;;charset=UTF-8');
header('cache-control: max-age=86400;');
header('Last-Modified: Tue, 15 Nov 1994 12:45:26 GMT;');
header('Expires: Sat, 22 Nov 2014 16:00:00 GMT;');
header('cache-control: max-age=86400;');
```

These are the other headers sent by default:

```
Connection:"Keep-Alive"
Content-Encoding:"gzip"
Content-Length:"393"
Date:"Fri, 21 Nov 2014 17:00:50 GMT"
Keep-Alive:"timeout=5, max=99"
Server:"Apache"
Vary:"Accept-Encoding"
X-Frame-Options:"SAMEORIGIN"
```

However, upon loading a page that references the `css.php` page multiple times, it continues to reload the CSS page every time.

### How do I know this...

I am receiving a hit to the `css.php` page every time I load the page which uses the stylesheet on my apache server access logs.

I can see that my Firefox browser is accessing the `css.php` page in the `Inspect Element` tool. It is receiving a `HTTP 200` every time.

What should I do?

Comment: you need to set headers expires time in advance. You're setting it for today, browsers normally cache the css anyway, the problems normally arise when someone changes the css and the browser has the cached version so the changes don't show up, this is backwards...

Comment: Today is the 21st. Plus, the CSS is not cached normally here because it is disguised as a PHP file.

Comment: Receiving a HTTP 200 is normal even if the item is cached. What you need to look for is `(from cache)` which is displayed in size/content column in Chrome DevTools (no idea about firefox).

Also keep in mind that most devtools disable that cache by default to you may need to untick the `disable cache` checkbox (in chrome this is at the top of the network panel)

Comment: @billy Don't worry, I lose days too... :)

Comment: @robjtede I see it in the server logs as well...

Comment: @HelpingHand It's fine. The page still requests sends a request out, the server acknowledges it and sends back "you already have this file in cache". If you see `(from cache)` in DevTools this is how you know it's working, not by the HTTP Statuses

Comment: @robjtede Wouldn't that be a `304 Not Modified`?

Comment: About 304 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978496/make-php-page-return-304-not-modified-if-it-hasnt-been-modified

Comment: @Cheery That's insane just to get a browser to cache a file for a day or a session!

Comment: @HelpingHand, I looked at the default headers....

Comment: @billy Ahh... gotcha. That just sends the current date.

Comment: @HelpingHand just to show, that 304 is not generated automatically in case of php scripts.

Comment: @Cheery Yeah, I knew that. Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: when I was writing in the comment box the page was scrolled down so couldn't see the tp box at the same time..note to self, read questions properly....

Comment: Could you not just use file_put_contents and write the file each time changes are made, That way all the browser sees is a normal css file?

Comment: @billy Haha... I've made the same mistake of jumping to answer without an understanding of the question. I think we all have made that mistake!

Comment: Maybe... I'll think about that...

Comment: if you dynamically write the link to the css each time the pages are created then you can add a version number on the end and when you change the css file just up the version number, that way any cached css's are updated.

Comment: @billy Write your file_put_contents() solution into an answer. It looks like that's what I'll do...

Comment: Did you check if the headers actually get sent?

Comment: Yeah, they are sent. I can see them with the `Inspect Element` tool on Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a dynamic CSS file, change the standard one each time with PHP's `file_put_contents()` function.

Example:

```
 file_put_contents("styles.css", $css_input);
```

That way, browsers will cache the file like normal.

Example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>
```

When you make changes the the actual CSS, browsers will automatically load the new one upon restart.

Comment: This is somewhat of a workaround... but gets the job done just the same! Thanks :)